# STL: Initializing a container with an unconstructed stateful comparator

Tags: c++, stl, construction

This has been running through my mind as a possible solution to an issue, however as it is a fairly obvious technical violation of *something* in C++, I wanted to know how likely to it is to fail, whether there is another fairly obvious approach, etc.  I'm hoping this doesn't get into a flamewar about undefined behavior, but considering the topic I do expect a little bit.

This is not the code I'm writing, I'm hoping it's not too simplified to not describe what I am attempting to do.

```c
class Code
{
public:
  bool read(short slot, short& val);
  bool read(short slot, long& val);
  bool read(short slot, double& val);
  // etc
protected:
  unsigned char* m_data;
};
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Code> CodePtr;

class SortedBase
{
protected:
   class Sorter : public std::binary_function<CodePtr,CodePtr,bool>
   {
   protected:
     inline Sorter() {}
     virtual ~Sorter() {}
   public:
     virtual bool operator()(CodePtr left, CodePtr right) PURE;
   };

   inline SortedBase(Sorter* s):m_codeList(s) {}

   typedef std::set<CodePtr,Sorter> TSortedCode;
   TSortedCode m_codeList;
public:
   virtual ~SortedBase() {}
   void fetch(); // populates m_codeList
};

template<class SORT1, class SORT2, class SORT3, class SORT4, class SORT5>
class SortedObject5 : public SortedBase
{
public:
  SortedObject5():SortedBase(m_sorter),m_sorter(this) {}

  something_interesting find(SORT1 val1, SORT2 val2, SORT3 val3, SORT4 val4, SORT5 val5);
protected:
  typedef SortedObject5<SORT1,SORT2,SORT3,SORT4,SORT5> my_class;
  class MySorter : public Sorter
  {
  public:
    MySorter(const my_class& parent):m_parent(parent) {}
    virtual operator()(CodePtr left, CodePtr right);
  protected:
    const my_class& m_parent;
  }

  MySorter m_sorter;
};
```

**The intent here**

I've often found when writing template classes that having a non-template base class with as much of the factored logic as possible is useful to both have some common class other code can reference and reduce the amount of code duplication, especially when making five different versions of the same class with different numbers of template parameters.

In this case the CodePtr is generated elsewhere in the code (although I did write it) and I would like to find elements based on an arbitrary number of arbitrary datatypes.  I considered a std::multimap at first but the key would end up being a wrapper to (or a copy of a significant chunk of) the CodePtr again.

**The problem**

I am passing the stateful sorter functor SortedObject5<>::my_sorter to the constructor of SortedBase::m_codeList.  However because the stateful sorter being in a sublcass, is fairly obviously not constructed at the point that the STL set is constructed.

I'm wondering if this is an issue if I don't make any inserts or searches in m_codeList from either constructor.

**Stateful sorter disclaimer**

I formally ASSERT() that the rules used by any stateful sort functor will change only while either the STL containers it controls are empty or will be clear()ed shortly afterwards.

Comment: I've never studied it in detail, but would Boost's [`base_from_member`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/base_from_member.html) help you?

Comment: Umm, ick? lol.  The technique _might_ be a good approach, and it definitely solves a similar (if not identical) issue.  It might take a bit of research to see whether I can use their packaged template or whether I'm stuck doubling my class count though.  So in short, the technique described in that page is a potential answer.

Comment: Doubling your class count? eh? you need one additional class to implement the base from member idiom. Make it a template and it can be reused for any types.

Comment: Except if the sorter class is itself a template class, as it is in this case.  It means splitting the template class into two, with a base to implement the sorter and a subclass to join the two together.  And I'm planning on having 4-5 templates here, with varying numbers of parameters.

Comment: A fairly obvious technical violation of _something_, everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `std::set<CodePtr,Sorter>` object stores an instance of `Sorter` **by value** so when you construct it with a `Sorter*` (did you mean that to  be a reference not a pointer?) it will slice the object and only keep the base part.

That means the `Sorter` copy constructor will run and make a copy of an uninitialized object. Undefined behaviour ensues.

That's assuming you can even create an instance of `Sorter`, if it's an abstract type you won't be able to (I don't know what your `PURE` does but I assume you're making the function pure virtual)

@Angew's comment suggest a good approach, the base from member idiom will allow you to ensure the `m_sorter` object is initialized first, which is part of the problem.  That doesn't help the issue of slicing though, to solve that you'd need some wrapper around the sorter e.g.

```
typedef std::function<bool(const CodePtr&,const CodePtr&)> SorterFunc;
typedef std::set<CodePtr, SorterFunc> TSortedCode;
```

And then pass the wrapper to the set constructor:

```
inline SortedBase(SorterFunc s) : m_codeList(s) {}
```

If you construct the `std::function` from the derived type it won't be sliced. It will be copied though, but you can prevent that by using a reference wrapper:

```
  SortedObject5() : BaseFrommember(this), SortedBase(SorterFunc(std::ref(m_sorter))) { }
```

Where `m_sorter` is already initialized, because it is stored in the `BaseFromMember` base class, using the base-from-member idiom.

This:

1. creates the `m_sorter` **first** so you don't do anything with an uninitialized object
2. passes it **by reference** to a `SorterFunc` object
3. uses a copy of that `SorterFunc` (still holding a reference to `m_sorter`) as the comparision function for the `std::set`

If you don't want to use the base-from-member idiom then it's still easy to avoid the undefined behaviour of your original code, just default construct the `set` (instead of passing it an uninitialized object) then assign a new value to it before you start populating it:

```
SortedObject5() : m_sorter(this)
{
  this->m_codeList = TSortedCode(SorterFunc(boost::ref(m_sorter)));
}
```

No new base classes, no extra templates, no undefined behaviour.

Here's the working code in full:

```
class SortedBase
{
protected:
   class Sorter : public std::binary_function<CodePtr,CodePtr,bool>
   {
   protected:
     Sorter() {}
     virtual ~Sorter() {}
   public:
     virtual bool operator()(const CodePtr& left, const CodePtr& right) = 0;
   };

   typedef boost::function<bool(const CodePtr&, const CodePtr&)> SorterFunc;

   typedef std::set<CodePtr,SorterFunc> TSortedCode;

   TSortedCode m_codeList;

public:
   virtual ~SortedBase() {}
   void fetch(); // populates m_codeList
};

template<class SORT1, class SORT2, class SORT3, class SORT4, class SORT5>
class SortedObject5 : public SortedBase
{
public:
  SortedObject5() : m_sorter(*this)
  {
    this->m_codeList = TSortedCode(SorterFunc(boost::ref(m_sorter)));
  }

protected:
  typedef SortedObject5<SORT1,SORT2,SORT3,SORT4,SORT5> my_class;

  class MySorter : public Sorter
  {
  public:
    MySorter(const my_class& parent):m_parent(parent) {}
    virtual bool operator()(const CodePtr& left, const CodePtr& right);
  protected:
    const my_class& m_parent;
  };

  MySorter m_sorter;
};
```

Comment: So... this sounds like it pretty much squishes any attempt to use a template stateful comparer here without pulling the set (and effectively all of the rest of the code referencing it) out of the base class.  Or is there some twist I'm not seeing?

Comment: Okay, read it a few more times.  It does look like there's the possibility of making this work, I guess the question is whether the extra few superclasses and wrapper classes are worth it.

Comment: My version **does** work (see updated answer with full example and no new classes) and your original doesn't even compile ... seems worth it to me.

Comment: Lol, I'm not surprised that my code wouldn't compile (I did write it fresh for the question), although I expected worse than a misplaced *.  I can confirm that your code does not require either a split template class or the Sorter to be broken out into its own class; replacing the base_from_member technique mentioned above with a double-contruction of m_codeList seems to be the big difference here (and if the original construction requires a parameter we can hand it a dummy Sorter object in the base class).  Thank you for the additional effort, this does seem like an authoritative answer.

Comment: Not just a misplaced `*`, the fact you can't instantiate `std::set` with an abstract type for the comparison was the showstopper :)