# How to use different comparators for a priority queue depending on conditions

Tags: c++, priority-queue, comparator

I'm working on an assignment, where I have a priority queue and I want it to work like this:

```
if(field == '0')
    priority_queue<record_t*,vector<record_t*>, CompareRecordID > pq;
else if(field == '1')
    priority_queue<record_t*,vector<record_t*>, CompareRecordNum > pq;
else if(field == '2')
    priority_queue<record_t*,vector<record_t*>, CompareRecordStr > pq;
else if(field == '3')
    priority_queue<record_t*,vector<record_t*>, CompareRecordNumStr > pq;
```

Where record_t is:

```
typedef struct {
   unsigned int recid;
   unsigned int num;
   char str[STR_LENGTH];
   bool valid;  // if set, then this record is valid
   int blockID; //The block the record belongs too -> Used only for minheap
} record_t;
```

Which means, depending on a function argument field, the queue will "sort" a different field of record_t. However, I cannot declare a queue inside an if statement, since it will obviously give me an error "pq was not declared in this scope". What can I do?

Comment: Use a stateful comparator.

Comment: @T.C. I'm trying to implement this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061613/c-declare-a-priority-queue-in-an-else-if
But I can't find a way to use this comparator inside the priority queue.

Comment: Do you really need to store pointers in your `queue`? Can you not just store the records?

Comment: @Galik Records are already stored somewhere else. I don't want them to be stored in two different places.

Comment: @Sofia Here are some explanations about how to use stateful comparators: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16616220/1413395

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `std::priority_queue` constructor that takes a comparator object as a parameter. Then you can feed it a configurable comparator a bit like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

const int STR_LENGTH = 20;

struct record_t
{
   unsigned int recid;
   unsigned int num;
   char str[STR_LENGTH];
   bool valid;  // if set, then this record is valid
   int blockID; //The block the record belongs too -> Used only for minheap
};

// switchable priority comparator
struct CompareRecord
{
    int field;

    CompareRecord(int field = 0): field(field) {}

    bool operator() (const record_t* lhs, const record_t* rhs) const
    {
        switch(field)
        {
            case 0: return lhs->recid < rhs->recid;
            case 1: return lhs->num < rhs->num;
            case 2: return std::strcmp(lhs->str, rhs->str) < 0;
        }
        return true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // physical records
    std::vector<record_t> records;

    record_t r;

    r.recid = 1;
    r.num = 1;
    std::strcpy(r.str, "banana");

    records.push_back(r);

    r.recid = 2;
    r.num = 4;
    std::strcpy(r.str, "orange");

    records.push_back(r);

    r.recid = 3;
    r.num = 2;
    std::strcpy(r.str, "apple");

    records.push_back(r);

    // input priority type: 0, 1 or 2

    int field;

    std::cout << "Sort type [0, 1, 2]: " << std::flush;
    std::cin >> field;
    std::cout << '\n';

    // build priority view

    CompareRecord cmp(field);
    std::priority_queue<record_t*, std::vector<record_t*>, CompareRecord> pq(cmp);

    for(auto& r: records)
        pq.push(&r);

    while(!pq.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "rec: " << pq.top()->recid << '\n';
        std::cout << "num: " << pq.top()->num << '\n';
        std::cout << "str: " << pq.top()->str << '\n';
        std::cout << '\n';
        pq.pop();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Sort type [0, 1, 2]: 0

rec: 3
num: 2
str: apple

rec: 2
num: 4
str: orange

rec: 1
num: 1
str: banana
```

Answer (score 1):

A priority_queue can take a comparator as a constructor argument.

```
std::priority_queue<record_t*,vector<record_t*>, CompareRecord > pq((CompareRecord(field)));
```

You just need to define the CompareRecord comparator appropriately.  A simple way to do it would be:

```
struct CompareRecord{
   char type;
   CompareRecord(char type):type(type){}
   bool operator()(const record_t* lhs, const record_t* rhs){
     switch(type){
        case '1': return lhs->recid < rhs->recid;
.. and so forth.

   }
```

}

Comment: I get this error now: 
error: request for member 'push' in 'pq', which is of non-class type 'std::priority_queue<record_t*, std::vector<record_t*>, CompareRecord>(CompareRecord)'|